# All Buttons on my form seem to be triggering "something"

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a windows form in which all the controls are created dynamically.

However, all the buttons seem to be triggering "Something" before the click event, and the "Something" is causing the selectedindexchanged of my comboboxes to fire. I have thoroughly gone through the event handlers declared, and made sure that none of the buttons have SIC pathed as their events.

I have noticed that the normal behaviour for clicking a button with a mouse is that when a button is clicked on but held down and released in an area outside of the button, the button is not triggered.

Interestingly in my case, the click itself triggers the "Something" even before the pressing is released.

Can anyone advise what is going on with my buttons?

Here is the InteliTrace events which I don't really seem to understand:

```
Calls for thread <No Name> (6976)
[System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()]
SESAdminForm.My.MyApplication.Main(String() Args = {String(0)})
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(string[]      commandLine = {unknown})]
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context = {unknown})
ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason = {unknown}, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context = {unknown})
ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason = {unknown}, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context = {unknown})
ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason = {unknown}, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context = {unknown})
System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd = {unknown}, int msg = {unknown}, System.IntPtr wparam = {unknown}, System.IntPtr lparam = {unknown})
ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {unknown})
ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {unknown})
System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {unknown})
System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {unknown})
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {unknown})
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {unknown}, System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons button = {unknown}, int clicks = {unknown})
System.Windows.Forms.Control.FocusInternal()
System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd = {unknown}, int msg = {unknown}, System.IntPtr wparam = {unknown}, System.IntPtr lparam = {unknown})
ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {unknown})
ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {unknown})
System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {unknown})
System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {unknown})
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {unknown})
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmSetFocus(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {unknown})
System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.ActivateControlInternal(System.Windows.Forms.Control control = {unknown})
System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.ActivateControlInternal(System.Windows.Forms.Control control = {unknown}, bool originator = {unknown})
System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.AssignActiveControlInternal(System.Windows.Forms.Control value = {unknown})
System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.UpdateFocusedControl()
System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.EnterValidation(System.Windows.Forms.Control enterControl = {unknown})
System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.ValidateThroughAncestor(System.Windows.Forms.Control ancestorControl = {unknown}, bool preventFocusChangeOnError = {unknown})
System.Windows.Forms.Control.PerformControlValidation(bool bulkValidation = {unknown})
System.Windows.Forms.Control.NotifyValidating()
System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnValidating(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e = {unknown})
System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.NotifyAutoComplete()
System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.NotifyAutoComplete(bool setSelectedIndex = {unknown})
Set System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.SelectedIndex(int value = {unknown})
System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged(System.EventArgs e = {unknown})
SESAdminForm.DataEntry.cBox_SelectionChangeCommittedUseItem2(Object sender = {System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs})
SESAdminForm.DataEntry.DisplayText()
```

-> There are 2 button-related messages but one seems to happen even before the mousedown event.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: i would, but because my program is dynamic n complex n i dont know where is the problem, i would most likely be posting u my entire code which is about 5k Lines. Im sure u dont want to go through that either.

Comment: i can only say that.. my form populates dynamic controls, and few of these is comboboxes that have selectedindexchanged events..
and once i fire up one SIC, the buttons begin to go haywire as mentioned.
However, if during the SIC event i remove handlers of all the other comboboxes, the buttons behave normally, but that would mean that if i continue to change the selection of the combobox, SIC wouldnt fire. And if i add the handler for the combobox at the end of the SIC event, the same issue arises.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar issue and the cause appears to be "duplicate" combobox entries (where the text is the same, but the value is not) and the auto complete I have set on the combobox. I don't have a fix, but the issue appears to be that all child elements of a form can be validated together, and validation triggers NotifyAutoComplete, which then can change the selected index.

Microsoft allude to the issue here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx with the comment "If there are duplicate entries in the maintained source, automatic completion behaves unpredictably."

Here is the source so you can understand what is going on;

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBox.cs,21e4308c05a79f0a

Essentially the call to ComboBox.OnValidating() checks if auto complete is enabled on the combobox. If it is then it assumes that we are validating because the user is typing. OnValidating calls into NotifyOnComplete and attempts to set the selected index, which is does by comparing text values. It's crude and not easy to circumvent.

My fix is going to be to turn off auto complete on my combo boxes before I call Form.ValidateChildren() which triggers this nonsense, and then reinstate the autocomplete values after validation.